# How to rectify HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception on Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am new to spring, after undergoing **javatpoint tutorials**, I tried to **create CRUD operation** of an **Student** using Eclipse IDE which is **similar to Employee CRUD**. While running I got output of ***index.jsp*** page whereas the following ***view, update, delete pages so many errors***.

***Student.java***

```
package com.spring.model;

public class Student {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
        public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

***StudentDao.java***

```
package com.spring.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import com.spring.model.Student;

public class StudentDao {

    JdbcTemplate template;
     /**
     * @param jdbcTemplate the jdbcTemplate to set
     */
    public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
    
    public int save(Student s)
    {
        String sql ="INSERT INTO student_detail (name,phone,address)VALUES('"+s.getName()+"','"+s.getPhone()+"','"+s.getAddress()+"')";
        return template.update(sql);
    }
    public int update(Student s)
    {
        String sql = "UPDATE student_detail SET name='"+s.getName()+"', phone='"+s.getPhone()+"', address='"+s.getAddress()+"' WHERE id="+s.getId()+"";
        return template.update(sql);
    }
    public int delete(int id)
    {
        String sql ="DELETE FROM student_detail WHERE id="+id+"";
        return template.update(sql);
    }
    public Student getStudentById(int id)
    {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM student_detail WHERE id=?";
            return template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Student>(Student.class));
    }
    public List<Student> getStudents()
    {
         return template.query("SELECT * FROM student_detail",new RowMapper<Student>(){    
                public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {    
                    Student s=new Student();    
                    s.setId(rs.getInt(1));    
                    s.setName(rs.getString(2));    
                    s.setPhone(rs.getString(3));    
                    s.setAddress(rs.getString(4));    
                    return s;    
                }    
            });    
    }
}
```

***StudentController.java***

```
package com.spring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.spring.dao.StudentDao;
import com.spring.model.Student;

@Controller
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    StudentDao dao;
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/studentform")
    public String showform(Model m)
    {
        m.addAttribute("command", new Student());
        return "studentform";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("Student") Student student)
    {
        dao.save(student);
        return "redirect:/viewstudent";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/viewstudent")
    public String viewstudent(Model m)
    {
        List<Student> list = dao.getStudents();
        m.addAttribute("list",list);
        return "/viewstudent";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/editstudent/{id}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable int id, Model m)
    {
        Student student = dao.getStudentById(id);
        m.addAttribute("command",student);
        return "studenteditform";
    }   
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/editsave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editsave(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student)
    {
        dao.update(student);
        return "redirect:/viewstudent";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/deletestudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String delete(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        dao.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/viewstudent";
    }
}
```

***index.jsp***

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello Gokul!</h2>

<a href="studentform">Add Student</a>
<a href="viewstudent">View Student</a>
</body>
</html>
```

***studentform.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>    
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Student | Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add New Student</h1>  
       <form:form method="post" action="save">    
        <table >    
         <tr>    
          <td>Name : </td>   
          <td><form:input path="name"  /></td>  
         </tr>    
         <tr>    
          <td>Phone :</td>    
          <td><form:input path="phone" /></td>  
         </tr>   
         <tr>    
          <td>Address :</td>    
          <td><form:input path="address" /></td>  
         </tr>   
         <tr>    
          <td> </td>    
          <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>    
         </tr>    
        </table>    
       </form:form>    
</body>
</html>
```

***viewstudent.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>    
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Student List</h1>  
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Address</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>  
   <c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">   
   <tr>  
   <td>${student.id}</td>  
   <td>${student.name}</td>  
   <td>${student.salary}</td>  
   <td>${student.designation}</td>  
   <td><a href="editstudent/${student.id}">Edit</a></td>  
   <td><a href="deletestudent/${student.id}">Delete</a></td>  
   </tr>  
   </c:forEach>  
   </table>  
   <br/>  
   <a href="empform">Add New Student</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

***editstudentform.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>    
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>    
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Edit Student | MVC Spring</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Edit Employee</h1>  
       <form:form method="POST" action="/MyApplication/editsave">    
        <table >    
        <tr>  
        <td></td>    
         <td><form:hidden  path="id" /></td>  
         </tr>   
         <tr>    
          <td>Name : </td>   
          <td><form:input path="name"  /></td>  
         </tr>    
         <tr>    
          <td>Phone :</td>    
          <td><form:input path="phone" /></td>  
         </tr>   
         <tr>    
          <td>Address :</td>    
          <td><form:input path="address" /></td>  
         </tr>   
           
         <tr>    
          <td> </td>    
          <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Save" /></td>    
         </tr>    
        </table>    
       </form:form>    
</body>
</html>
```

***web.xml***

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
  <servlet>
  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>   
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

***spring-servlet.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller"></context:component-scan>    
        
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">    
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>    
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>    
</bean>    
    
<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">    
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>    
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_mvc"></property>    
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>    
    <property name="password" value="Brownie@753"></property>    
</bean>    
    
<bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">    
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>    
</bean>    
    
<bean id="dao" class="com.spring.dao.StudentDao">    
    <property name="template" ref="jt"></property>    
</bean>       
</beans>
```

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.spring.student</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyApplication</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MyApplication Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MyApplication</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

### ERROR MESSAGE

- 

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
type Exception report
message Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.spring.dao.StudentDao] for bean with name 'dao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.spring.dao.StudentDao
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1281)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1350)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:916)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.spring.dao.StudentDao
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1273)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1350)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:916)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.9 logs.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.9
```

- 

OUTPUT SCREEN

index out

[image]

error page

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images. Edit your question and add the information as text.

Comment: Will add i am new to this i don't used to post q/a in sstackoverflow but someone updated it i don't know who

Answer (score 0):

In `StudentDao` you have a property named `template`, however the setter of this property is named "differently", `setJdbcTemplate`. So in your `spring-servlet.xml` when you try to set the bean `dao` you try to set a property named `template` but it has no corresponding setter inside `StudentDao` thus you get the error in your screenshots.

You can do 2 things,

either rename the setter in `StudentDao` from:

```
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}
```

to:

```
public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}
```

**OR**

rename your `template` property in `StudentDao` to `jdbcTemplate`, adjust the setter accordingly e.g.

```
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = template;
}
```

and change your `spring-servlet.xml` as:

```
<bean id="dao" class="com.spring.dao.StudentDao">    
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jt"></property>    
</bean>
```

Comment: i have doubt as per your answers and i get output too, now i changed java 1.5 -> 1.8 now same error throws what shall i do?

Comment: I dont think my suggestions above are prone to java version changes. Are you sure you have applied my suggestions and cleaned/built your project with java 8? Can't help you further with so few info, if it worked with java 5 it should work with java 8 unless you have other errors in other parts of your code.

Comment: what info you need to rectify this issues, if you could elaborate I shall able to clear my doubts and explore more in spring @pleft

Comment: For start, have you added the stacktrace on your post to reflect the current errors i.e. with java 8?

Comment: Also have you noted that the errors in screenshots (the initial ones that my answer tries to solve) are different than the one in the error stacktrace you have posted afterwards ClassNotFoundException? My answer solved your initial question, and apparently you accepted it, however after you did other changes e.g. switch from java 5 to 8 and you have other exceptions. These other exceptions belong to a different question, it is not easy to constantly update my answer depending on what errors you meet while coding your app.

Comment: shall i post another q/a??

Comment: If `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.spring.dao.StudentDao` is the new error that you get it means that either `StudentDao` does not exist in your code at all (have you deleted it accidentally?), or maybe it is in a different package than `com.spring.dao`. Or your project does not build correctly. Carefully check the above and do a clean build of your project. If you still cannot resolve it I would suggest to open a new Question and provide exact details of your project structure, configuration etc and the errors you get.